# Can't Insert data to database ms-access vb

Tags: vb.net

Case 1: i can't insert data to my database

```
  Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ProjectVB.accdb")
```

Case 2: i can insert data to my database

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\ProjectVB.accdb")
```

database was saved in my project already

```
conn.Open()

            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ac_ID", txtID.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ac_pass", txtPassword.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nation_ID", txtNoID.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fName", txtFirstName.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lName", txtLastName.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel", txtTel.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@province", cbNation.SelectedItem)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@regOn", dtRegOn.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", txtStatus.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", cbGender.SelectedItem)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", txtLocation.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", imgBuffer)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rank", cbRank.SelectedItem)
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO db_KJ_Profile VALUES(@ac_ID,@ac_pass,@nation_ID,@fName,@lName,@tel,@province,@regOn,@status,@gender,@location,@img,@rank)"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Can you read from the database in the first case?

Comment: Yes. I can read but can't insert.

Comment: Did you get error messages or just you don't find the data inserted when you check your database?

Comment: Show us your insert code

Comment: Don't find the data inserted when check my database.

Comment: `cmd.CommandText = "INSERT ...` should not be placed before adding parameters?

Comment: add parameters after `cmd.CommandText`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the DataDirectory substitution string you should check the content of the database in the folder `PROJECTFOLDER\BIN\DEBUG` (or x86 version of the same path).

This is due to the fact that in a WinForms application, when running in a debug session of VS, the `DataDirectory` points to the folder where your application is executed (The BIN\DEBUG or BIN\x86\DEBUG subfolder of the project folder).

This is easy to overlook and it is always a source of confusion.
And it is worse if you have the ACCDB file listed in your project items. In this case the database item has a property called `Copy To The Output Directory`. You should check that is set to `Copy If Newer or Copy Never` and not to `Copy Always` because in this case, at every restart of your debug session a new copy of the database is copied (of course without the just inserted data) from your project folder to the BIN\DEBUG folder

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I set properties to Copy If Newer and my database was updated.