# Why it doesn't insert into sql table?

Tags: c#, sql, insert

This is my code for insert into a table. It doesn't get any error, but it doesn't insert to the table. I tried by using `stored_procedure` too but it doesn't insert too. I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.bm_DatabaseConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [tbl_Buildings] (buildingName,buildingImage,buildingAddress,floorNo,apartsNo, buildingDesc) VALUES (@builName,@builImage,@builAddr,@floorNo,@apartsNo,@builDesc)";//"prc_AddNewBuilding";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@builName", txtBuildingName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@builAddr", txtAddress.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@builImage", "Undefined");
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@floorNo", (int)numFloorNo.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@apartsNo", (int)numApartsNo.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@builDesc", txtBuilDesc.Text);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("New building has been added successfully");
        this.Close(); 
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(sqlex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

I am using VS2012. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What is your connection string? And how do you check if  the insert has succeed or not?

Comment: hi steve ;this is my con_string="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AppData\bm_Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET application? If yes the App_Data folder is already part of the DataDirectory substitution string

Comment: NO this is a win app.

Comment: How do you know that it isn't working?

Comment: Then check if you have a database file  in YOURPROJECT\BIN\DEBUG\APPDATA\bm_Database.mdf

Comment: but I don't have any DataDirectory ! I just add a directory called 'AppData' and placed my DB there.

Comment: DataDirectory is a substitution string used to facilitate the deployment of your application. In a debug session of VS it is resolved (for WinForms) in the PROJECTFOLDER\BIN\DEBUG so, your insert happens in a database located there

Comment: I right clicked on table name in 'ServerExplorer' and clicked on 'Show table data' but its empty;

Comment: @Steve
I have my DB in myProj\bin\debug\AppData\bm_Database.mdf

Comment: But the connection used by server explorer is myProj\appdata\bm_database.mdf. Today is the second case of this scenario. Please look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184732/cant-insert-data-to-database-ms-access-vb/21185028#21185028) (it is for Access, but the problem is identical)

Comment: @steve
I changed that property but I got this error when I tried to build app .
**Error 30 Unable to copy file "E:\c\Practice\C#\BuildingManager\BuildingManager\AppData\bm_Database_log.ldf" to "bin\Debug\AppData\bm_Database_log.ldf". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\AppData\bm_Database_log.ldf' because it is being used by another process. BuildingManager
**

Comment: thank you @steve now it is working . How can I rate your comment as an answer? 
I am new in Stackoverflow.com :P

Comment: You could upvote the other answer of mine if you found it helpful, of course the site requires at least 15 reps before allowing you to do so. But it is really easy to get it if you stay around here for a bit

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

**My original answer assumed SQL Server was the database.  As it turns out, the OP is using MS Access.  Seems, based on other evidence, the file path for the .mdb file was the culprit, not the C# or SQL.**

**My original answer:**

Using the connection string...

```
Server=myhost;Database=testdatatbase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

the code you provided above works.  I went to SQL Enterprise Manager, created a table named dbo.tbl_Buildings with the following attributes...

```
buildingName = nvarchar(50)
buildingImage = nvarchar(50)
buildingAddress = nvarchar(50)
floorNo = int
apartsNo = int
buildingDesc = nvarchar(50)
```

I then passed in dummy values, then ran the following query...

```
select * from testdatatbase.dbo.tbl_Buildings
```

and it shows the record....

-- seems to work for me...

(Maybe check your datatypes - make sure your table types match your types in the code)

Comment: thank you @barrypicker
I found my answer [in this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184732/cant-insert-data-to-database-ms-access-vb/21185028#21185028)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
Database.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variableName", variable)
```

The only thing I could imagine why your values won't be inserted into your DB is a SQL Exception. Maybe you're missing some quotes?

Alternatiely use the complete "Add" Statement like this:

```
Database.Command.Parameters.Add(item, System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
```

Item in this case is your variable containing the data you want to store

Comment: ...what?  He's already using parameters (thankfully), and I doubt that's _directly_ the problem.  If at all possible, always provide an example of things to try, **not** just list out generalities.  It makes for better answers, especially if the question asker (or anybody else) doesn't have much experience in the direction you're suggesting.

Comment: I'm very sorry 'bout that crap I wrote. Try using **Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variableName", variable)**. The only thing I could imagine why your values won't be inserted into your DB is a SQL Exception. Maybe you're missing some quotes?

Comment: Alternatiely use the _complete_ "Add" Statement like this: **Database.Command.Parameters.Add(item, System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input** _item_ is your variable containing the data you want to store.